# Pointer to a cell matrix c++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I have a matrix, for example, `int m[10][10]`, and i want point to a specific cell, how can I do this?

I tried with:

```
float *p; 
p=&m[1][1];
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your types - it wouldn't work with `int x; float *p = &x;` either.

You need either `float[10][10]` or `int* p`.